# is it better to mutate the state in setState or make a clone of it?

Tags: reactjs

This is my state:

```
state = {
    people: [
      { name: "aaa", age: 35 },
      { name: "bbb", age: 36 },
      { name: "ccc", age: 32 }
    ]
  };
```

and I want to change the second name to `xxx`. I use Lodash and this is what I do and it works:

```
const newPeople = _.cloneDeep(this.statae.people);
newPeople[1].name = "xxx";
this.setState({people: newPeople});
```

But I feel I'm overkilling it and being a bit too picky!

Because when I removed the deep clone and just used the mutated state in setState it worked again:

```
 const newPeople = this.state.people;
    newPeople[1].name = "xxx";
    this.setState({people: newPeople});
```

But my doubt comes from the fact that I have heard it's always a good practice to not mutate but work with real clones.

NOW,

The first question is, do you agree with my clone here or no you think it's too much?

The second question is, if you want me to use the state itself, not the clone, in this scenario do I need to use that format of setState that we pass a function `this.setState((currentState,props)=>())`?

Comment: "Because when I removed the deep clone and just mutate the state itself it worked again." - I doubt that's true, it won't re-render. Show us how it works.

Comment: If you do `this.state.something = something` it will change the state, but it won't rerender the component. Doing this is also a bad practice and will lead to problems

Comment: I should say that in all case I used setState at the end, but in the second one, I use mutated state in setstate.

Comment: @DennisVash sorry for misleading, I edited my question.

Comment: @Vencovsky sorry for misleading, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you agree with my clone here or no you think it's too much?

You have to make a deep copy **in order to render** the component, but there is no reason to use `lodash` here:

```js
this.state.people[1].name = "xxx";
this.setState({ people: ...this.state.people });

// More readable
const newPeople = this.state.people                   // Shallow copy
newPeople[1].name = "xxx";
this.setState({ people: ...newPeople });
```

When you making **shallow-copy**, it wont work:

```js
const newPeople = this.state.people;  // Shallow-copy
newPeople[1].name = "xxx";
this.setState({people: newPeople});   // Won't Render because newPeople === this.state.people
```

You can see an example I made [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3yo21pvzy?fontsize=14).

> if you want me to use the state itself, not the clone, in this scenario do I need to use that format of setState that we pass a function this.setState((currentState , props )=>())?

**If your new state relay** on `prevState`
remember that state can be **Asynchronous**, React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.

`this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

```js
const newPeople = this.state.people
newPeople[1].name = "xxx" + props.newName;
this.setState({ people: ...newPeople })                // Bad on high traffic

this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {              // Good
const newPeople = prevState.people;
newPeople[1].name = "xxx" + prevProps.newName;
return { people: ...newPeople }
}
```

In your case, just use `this.setState({ people: ...newPeople })`